# Changing data type from String in yyyy-MM-dd format to DateType

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I am trying to convert a column in a dataframe from yyyy-MM-dd formatted string types to DateType.

I am currently running this code but it doesn't change the type, but it also doesn't fail to run- so I figure I'm missing something fairly basic

```
data.calendar = py.to_date(data.calendar, format="DateType")
```

I got this format from http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#to_date but I'm not sure what I'm missing

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I think your code does not execute until you call collect on PySpark dataframes.

Try:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

# Assuming that data is your pyspark dataframe
result = data.select(to_date(data.calendar)).collect()

# or if your data does not have format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
result = data.select(to_date(data.calendar, format='some_other_format')).collect()
```

Spark uses lazy evaluation, meaning that you "queue up" operations to be applied to a dataframe. Those operations are executed when you use an action, such as `collect`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.select(to_timestamp(df.t, 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('dt')).collect()
```